# Connection between word usage frequency and number of synonyms for the word

Tags: frequency, synonymy

At a first glance it seems to be obvious/expectable (at least to some extent) that the more frequently a word is used in language the more synonyms it should have.

Can somebody point out whether this has been proved scientifically/statistically and works/publications some data on this?

Comment: I think this could be tricky, because synonymy is usually gradient. However, the data are certainly out there: for English, you could get some kind of 'semantic neighborhood' score from WordNet, and a frequency score from various corpora (COCA, etc.).